# Is it possible to use List.unfold to list all factors of N?

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I'm trying to wrap my head around functional programming using F#. I'm sticking to purely mathematical problems for now.

My current problem is simple enough: to write a function that takes an integer `N` and outputs a `list` of all the factors of N

Because of the similarities between `sequences` and C# `IEnumerables` formed by `yield return` I got this solution:

```
let seqFactorsOf n =
    seq { for i in 2 .. (n / 2) do if n % i = 0 then yield i }
```

I don't think `lists` can be generated that way, though, so I turned to `List.unfold`:

```
let listFactorsOf n =
    2 |> List.unfold (fun state ->
        if state <= n / 2 then
            if state % 2 = 0 then
                Some (state, state + 1)
            else
                //need something here to appease the compiler. But what?
        else
            None)
```

My other attempt uses the concept of matching, with which I'm almost totally unfamiliar:

```
let listFactorsOf_2 n =
    2 |> List.unfold(fun state ->
        match state with
        | x when x > n / 2 -> None
        | x when n % x = 0 -> Some(x, x + 1)
        //I need a match for the general case or I get a runtime error
        )
```

Is there a way to create such `list` using `List.unfold`? Please notice that I'm a beginner (I started F# 3 days ago) and the documentation is not very kind to newbies, so if you'd try to be as didactic as possible I would appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First** - yes, of course lists can be generated using that `for..in` syntax (it's called "*list comprehensions*" by the way). Just put the whole thing in square brackets instead of `seq { }`:

```
let seqFactorsOf n =
    [ for i in 2 .. (n / 2) do if n % i = 0 then yield i ]
```

---

As for `unfold` - every iteration is required to either produce an element of the resulting list (by returning `Some`) or to signal end of iteration (by returning `None`). There is nothing you can return from the body of `unfold` to indicate "skipping" the element.

Instead, what you have to do is to somehow "skip" the unwanted elements yourself, and only ever return the next divisor (or `None`).

One way to do that is with a helper function:

```
let rec nextDivisor n i =
    if n % i = 0 then Some i
    else if i >= n/2 then None
    else nextDivisor n (i+1)
```

Let's test it out:

```
nextDivisor 16 3
> Some 4

nextDivisor 16 5
> Some 8

nextDivisor 16 10
> None
```

Now we can use that in the body of `unfold`:

```
let listFactorsOf n =
    2 |> List.unfold (fun state ->
        match nextDivisor n state with
        | Some d -> Some (d, d + 1)
        | None -> None
    )
```

---

As a bonus, the construct `match x with Some a -> f a | None -> None` is a well-known and widely used concept usually called "map". In this particular case - it's `Option.map`. So the above can be rewritten like this:

```
let listFactorsOf n =
    2 |> List.unfold (fun state ->
        nextDivisor n state 
        |> Option.map (fun d -> d, d+1)
    )
```

Comment: Really awesome, thank you! Glad to see I can use the old yield return (simplified to just yield in F#), but the other solution is fascinating. I must learn how to think like that. The fact that there is an alternative syntax for matching isn't very reassuring for a beginner. It will probably take a while until I'm able to look at both as the same thing. F# could use some powerful refactor tools... Such tools teach a lot about alternate syntaxes in C#: you just cycle through the refactor's suggestions and learn all the ways one same coding idea can be expressed.

Comment: Wait, what alternative syntax for matching?

Comment: `Option.map` is not a syntax, it's a function. In its implementation it does use the `match` syntax.

Comment: I see. I'm still very new to this world of functional programming. What I meant is that when I see `Option.map` instead of `match x with |Some y -> ... |None -> None` it will require an extra effort on my part to realize they mean the same thing. So, when I'm reading code to learn, this will be a problem. Just like the way you can write the tuple without parenthesis like you did is something that will take a while to sink in when I'm reading other people's codes.